# Burying AC, solar DC and ethernet cable

Tags: conduit, ethernet

I am building a pole barn about 200 feet from my house.  I would like to run 90amp or so 240VAC to a subpanel, as well as ~400VDC from solar panels, and a pull or perhaps two of Cat5e ethernet cable.

The 240VAC will go to a subpanel in the pole barn, and will be 4 conductor (L1, L2, N and G). The subpanel will also be tied to a ground rod at the pole barn.

The 400VDC will likely be 3 pair, and will go from solar panels to inverters at the house, which tie into an existing grid connected solar system.

The ethernet will have two runs, mostly for redundancy.  I only need one.  I have considered running more, but a better solution might be to put a POE switch in the barn, and use POE to run cameras.

Each group of lines would run in their own conduit.  I will try to keep the ethernet conduit away from the others in the trench.

I am considering using aluminum wire for the 240VAC and the solar, for cost.  I would probably want to try to go with copper for the solar, since it would frequently cycle between maximum power and no power more often than the 240VAC.

Is 10" suitable separation for the Cat5e? Any other suggestions?

Comment: How many amps of solar are we talking?

Comment: Two 40A pairs at about 400VDC.  May split into three pairs.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't site the inverters at the barn? Hauling 400VDC over the underground conduit poses some...interesting issues.  Also, where are you on this planet?

Comment: Inverters in the barn would complicate the combiner/disconnect for existing solar and wind generation.  Losses at 400VDC are less than at 240VAC.  I already have longer runs for existing panels. What are the concerns about 400VDC in conduit?  I have experienced no issues with existing 10yo system. Help me understand the concerns with DC which would want one to send AC from the barn?

Comment: @mongo -- you'd need to do some jiggery-pokery to accomplish rapid shutdown of the array on the polebarn (at least if you're under NEC jurisdiction -- your posts on Av.SE make me think you might be in Canada?)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, not in Canada, the installation is in US.  Also, inverters in the barn would require service to the barn, which would be an additional meter, and a new run from the transformer.  It would mean that I would be running two separate services.  I could still have one service remote from the other, but only one way, and it would double my grid tie costs.

Comment: @mongo -- why would inverters at the barn require a *service* to the barn? Who's your electrical utility?

Comment: The way I see it is a 40A 400VDC pair would have to be upgraded to a higher gauge to handle the 67A that would be needed for 240VAC.  Since I have two, or perhaps three of those pairs, that would nearly double my costs for wire alone.  AND I would have to install a new combiner and line disconnect at the barn.  So sending 400VDC to the garage looks more attractive.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, you ask why inverters at the barn would require a service to the barn.  First, that was required by a neighbor, and his system had to be rebuilt by his contractor to be accepted. I don't know the details, and I don't want that kind of hassle. Second, without the second service, I would have to handle another 135A at 240VAC to get the power back to the combiner.  My combiner will not handle that gauge of wire, so I need a combiner which would be structurally different. Very expensive.

Comment: @mongo -- AC doesn't need dedicated "combiners" -- an ordinary breaker box can handle that duty

Comment: @mongo -- in any case, who's your electric utility?

Comment: I do not have a panel box which will accept more than one breaker with two 4/0 connections.

Comment: @mongo -- what make and model are your breaker boxes? (the only type of panel that I know that's true for are Eaton CH panels because CH2150s and 2200s got discontinued a while ago)

Comment: @mongo -- can you *please* tell us who your electric utility is in any case? I'm seriously baffled by what your neighbor went thru

Comment: @mongo -- also, am I correct in presuming that the existing inverters are grid-tied transformerless string units, or are they some other type of inverter or charge controller?

Answer (score 1):

For networking, use fiber optics, or point-to-point wireless.

By the time you provide adequate lightning suppression (UL497 Primary Protection) on copper ethernet, fiber is likely cheaper, and it's definitely more robust. I've never replaced a fiber for a nearby strike, but it's not uncommon to need to replace surge protectors after a storm.

If there's a clear shot, point to point wireless also works well, and may feel more accessible (fiber is not all that difficult, but it can feel daunting to get started with.)

There's really no advantage to using copper wires .vs. appropriately sized aluminum wires for the other two circuits. A thing you might want to consider would be skipping the DC circuit entirely by putting an inverter at the barn.

Comment: If you put the inverter at the barn, would there be code issues with putting both AC circuits in one sufficiently large conduit?

Comment: If it's grid tie inverter, you don't *need* two circuits for AC. You tie into the grid at the barn for the barn inverter. Bim, Bam, one AC cable, and perhaps a fiber, and you're done. Depending on the cost of each, it might cost less to have an inverter at the barn than to run an extra circuit.

Comment: Placing the inverters in the barn would necessitate changes with service, combiners and code required shutoffs.  Additionally, the losses may be greater transporting 240VAC vs 400VDC.  I will double check wires, but last time I ran service Al was nearly a quarter of the cost of copper.  For ethernet, wireless will not work, but I will look at fiber.  Last time I checked the cost was several hundred.  Copper is substantially less as a Cat5e to the building would cost about $8.00.

Comment: Definitely fiber rather than wireless whenever possible. As far as AC vs. DC: There might (depending on the utility setup and how net metering works/priced) also be an issue because then you might have to have a separate meter/service drop for the barn, and if that's the case and your actual barn usage is far lower than the main building then with that much solar it may not work out so well.

Comment: A quick looks suggests that UL497 surge protection will add about $140 to your $8. And your $8 sounds suspiciously like a cable not suitable for wet locations, which will come back to bite you if that's the case.

Comment: $8.00 for 200' of CAT5e, @mongo? I wanna know where you're getting your cable!!!

Comment: @FreeMan, look for five star cat5e cable at Amazon, 1000ft $45.85.

Comment: ...as expected, NOT suitable for use in exterior conduit.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, if I put the Cat5e cable into PVC conduit, it should remain dry, and without issues, right?  I have done that between buildings for Cat5, telephone 4 conductor wire and other low voltage signal wires, and not had any problems, since I built my house in 1983..As for UL497 devices, I suppose that every eave mounted camera should also have one of those devices?  And perhaps I should insist that my ISP also provide that level of protection at the service entrance?  Because they do not. Besides there is a LAN limit of 100 feet with such a device, so it will not work.

Comment: All outdoor conduit IS WET. It's DEFINED as wet, and it lives up to that definition.

Comment: Given the choices then, I will opt for using the inferior Cat5e cable in conduit, as opposed to fiber.  And take my chances with the LAN connectivity.

Comment: @mongo -- your ISP provides that protection at the service entrance through the lightning protector they provided at their demarcation point, at least if they're a telco or cableco

Comment: @mongo -- also, where are you getting that 100' limit for a UL497 primary protector from? The protectors I've been able to find (ITWLinx units) don't have such a thing documented anywhere I can find